# Alternating colour striped material

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm attempting to understand how to use nodes and currently trying to create a material which involves a pair of alternating coloured stripes. Think of a barcode, or hazard stripes.

In my first attempt, I tried using a checker texture node, which took vector information from a mapping node. In this node, I used the point setting, and scaled it so that X and Y were .1, while Z was 1. The mapping vector information was then obtained from a generated texture coordinate node.

This seemed to be fine for two out of three axes, as the X and Y had stripes. However, I could not figure out how to apply the stripes to the Z axis, which remained a solid colour. I can see why this is so, but I don't know how to create an alternative solution.

Another limitation with what I tried is that if I were to set mapping rotation to 45 degrees for example, I would get solid colours on two axes, and triangular alternates on the third, which is definitely not what I'm trying to make.

So basically, how can I create a material which is striped in all axes, and can be rotated without any sort of distortion or deformation?

Comment: The thing is, any manifold will have at least 1 singularity, so it is mathematically impossible to create strips without disconnecting them.
However if you would allow discontinuity you can create strips in 2 axis and other 2 axis and mix between them. (Can you do this?)
Also, did you have a look at the wave texture node?

Answer (score 3):

This can also be accomplished with the checker texture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Separate the generated texture coordinates vector, connect a *math* node set to *sine* to one of the coordinates, connect the output to a *math* node set to *greater than*, and connect that output to a *mix RGB* node.

[image]

The result:

[image]

If you want stripes on all sides, it is probably best to UV unwrap the mesh and use the UV texture coordinates as input for the node setup.

Comment: Seems alright. I've added a mapping node between the first and second in your screenshot and tried giving it a 45 degree angle on the Z axis. I've noticed that the stripes adjust to the dimensions of the mesh, and is therefore only truly 45 degrees when the mesh is a cube (as opposed to a rectangle). Any idea how to work around that?

Comment: I stretched the cube to twice its length and added a Mapping node and rotated by 45 degrees.  The stripes stayed at 45 degrees.  I used the Camera output of the Texture Coordinates.  I confess that I don't know what using this output means, but it worked.