# Create distorted striped material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I'm trying to make a mountain model in Blender with distorted striped layers. Based on [this solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72535/alternating-colour-striped-material) I made striped layers but I need to have distorted layers in the final model as well. I mean something like [this](http://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/nodes/sop/heightfield_visualize.html). I tried to add a random value to the Sine function (using Object info node) but it didn't work. Can you please help me to add this kind of distortions to my model?

[image]

Comment: Just add a Noise Texture and connect the Factor out to the Greater Than empty input.

Comment: @rob Thank you for your answer. But actually this isn't what I want to have. Your suggested solution makes noise only on the edges of stripes but I want to have noise on the whole stripe. This is the result of your solution: [scr1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p8LuYIIm1_v9F5laxyxkc5rEdTq87Cag/view?usp=sharing) and this is what I want to have: [scr2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4Cfns5db_u3YVOTz-TLzErI7tvyWPyL/view?usp=sharing) (I edited the second image with GIMP)

Comment: update the question with the images. Question updates are seen by more people than comments. I think you can affect the texture coordinates to create the effect you want but I am unsure how.

Comment: Try to use what I made and tweak the settings. I think your wished effect is maximal one node away from my solution. I can try later to tweak it a little to make it look exactly like in your image. But I want to encourage you to try it yourself and see if you learn something by it.

Comment: I found the solution with your help. Thanks @HenrikD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have special reasons for the DIY math, it might be easier to use the built-in distortion option of the Wave texture node?

[image]

The nodes:

[image]

Comment: you know whats funny... I did know you could do it like this but I hate that Mapping Node. I think it is really unpractical and hard to setup correct. A simple Vector is much simpler I though, so thats what I made.

Comment: @HenrikD .. and if you want more controllable specific distortion, as in the OP's last illustration, you still have to get the math nodes out anyway, to distort the texture space of one noise with another  noise, or waves... etc etc.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure if you asked google on this you would find fitting Materials. But you seamingly didn't and neither did I. So I made the following setup to be as parametric as possible, since you didn't make clear what you want to achieve.
[image]

There are those named fields that you can use to tweak the distortion and there is the color selector on the left on which you can specify the direction of the lines. You can also replace that color selector by a Combine XYZ Node to gain better access to the numbers of the normal vector. Hope this solution can satisfy your needs.

EDIT:
If you want to make the texture that you showed in your post, you just need to turn the distortion of the noise texture up. I pretty much got it to match your image.